# Android soap client - parsing errors

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2, soap-client

So here is my problem. I want to create `SOAP` client on android device which will talk with server i made.

I Have found out that the only possible and the easiest way to do so is to use `kSOAP2` library. And I have followed the example. Here is my `WSDL`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
xmlns:tns="http://test/ExampleWs.php" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" 
xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
targetNamespace="http://test/ExampleWs.php" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://test/ExampleWs.php">
      <s:element name="Login">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="login" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="LoginResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="loginResult" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="sid" type="s:string" /> 
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="LoginSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Login" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="LoginResponseSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:LoginResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="TestServiceSoap">

    <wsdl:operation name="Login">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:LoginSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:LoginResponseSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

 <wsdl:binding name="TestServiceSoap" type="tns:TestServiceSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Login">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://test/ExampleWs.php?Login" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="testService">
    <wsdl:port name="testServiceSoap" binding="tns:testServiceSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://test/ExampleWs.php?" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

and my method which want to `Call` login function on this `Webservice`:

```
public void LoginToWsdl(){
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://test/ExampleWs.php?Login";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "Login";
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://test/ExampleWs.php";
    final String URL = "http://test/wsdl/test.wsdl";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("login", "grzes");
    request.addProperty("password", "grzes");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        String response =envelope.getResponse().toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        
}
```

The problem is that all the time i get `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}wsdl:definitions targetNamespace='http://test/ExampleWs.php'>@10:99 in java.io.InputStreamReader@45ce5068)`

When i use `SoapUI` to test my webservice everything work well. Can anyone point me out where I am doing mistake?

Comment: Noone have faced similiar problem? :(